# Using Flowpaper in an Angular 4 component?

Tags: angular, typescript, flexpaper

I'm getting the error `Property 'FlexPaperViewer' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'` I am loading the `Flexpaper.js` via the `.angular-cli.json` file but my component.ts file isn't able to reference it thus the error.

Note: I'm pretty green with Angular and TypeScipt. Any help is greatly appreciated.